# yview_moveto going to incorrect position when used after updating ScrolledText contents

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a software that involves making a text editor that the contents are being updated very often (every time the user types something it syncs the values in the text with something else)

The way that I do this is by saving the cursor position and scrollbar position and text (it is a `ScrolledText` widget)

```
self.scroll_data = self.text.yview()
text = self.text.get("1.0", tkinter.END)[:-1]
cursor = self.text.index(tkinter.INSERT)
```

After putting the `text` through the function that syncs it, I now have the string that should be in the `ScrolledText` widget (`self.text`)

Now That I have the text That should be in the widget I do this to put the text in and have it look to the user like nothing happened by replacing the text and resetting the cursor position and scroll bar position

```
self.text.delete("1.0", tkinter.END)
self.text.insert("1.0", self.mod.get_text()) # self.mod.get_text() is the text that we want
self.text.mark_set("insert", str(cursor))
self.text.yview_moveto(self.scroll_data[0])
```

I then call `self.root.update()` because I want the window the show the changes.

This is where I am having the problem, for some reason, because I am moving the scrollbar after resetting the text but not updating, it causes a weird bug where the scrollbar inches up whenever I type something. This doesn't happen every single time I tried it in the past but even old version are having this issue for me right now.

I way I found that somewhat fixes the issue is to call `self.root.update()` on the line before `self.text.yview_moveto(self.scroll_data[0])` but that causes a visual glitch where the text jumps to the top for a short period of time every time you type a character.

Because it goes to the correct scrolling position when I do that it leads me to believe that it is a problem with calling `yview_moveto` before updating the screen after deleting and setting text.

This script is an example of the bug in action:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.scrolledtext
root = tkinter.Tk()
x = tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root)
x.pack()
last_text = ""
while True:
    text = x.get("1.0", tkinter.END)[:-1]
    changed = text != last_text
    if changed:
        text = "a" + text
        scroll_data = x.yview()
        cursor = x.index(tkinter.INSERT)
        x.delete("1.0", tkinter.END)
        x.insert("1.0", text)
        x.mark_set("insert", cursor)
        x.yview_moveto(scroll_data[0])
    last_text = text
    root.update()
```

If anyone knows how to solve this issue I would greatly appreciate if you would share your solution with me so I can ensure a smooth user experience for anyone using my tool

 (this is a link to the github repo with my project https://github.com/hippolippo/Unity-Mod-Maker)
*EDIT: I found out that the reason this happens is because some of the lines of text get automatically pushed to the next line because they are too long to fit on the screen. I still don't have a solution however*

Comment: I would really suggest that you use `mainloop` to handle events and remove that `while` loop. you can use `after` "loops" or `threading` (with `after` "loops") to update widgets periodically, that way scrolling won't likely be affected, also I don't exactly get what issue you are having, the only visual glitch I notice is the scrollbar's slider resizing

Comment: Is there a specific reason you've got your own event loop rather than using tkinter's `mainloop`? `mainloop` is likely going to be more efficient.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have many windows that pop up and I have code that needs to run every tick

Comment: @Hippolippo: you don't need a custom event loop to do that.

Comment: I don't think I see any sort of visual artifact when I run the code in the question. What are we supposed to do and see?

Comment: @BryanOakley https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__hq1zNYZ0I The text scrolls up every time you type a character

Comment: @Matiiss I originally used mainloop in the past but it gave me issues once I created several windows and I tried threading but apparently tkinter doesn't work well with multiple threads (note that the example that I gave is not my actual program but just a [MCVE])

Comment: @BryanOakley I made an edit to my question because it seems like the bug only happens when there is a line that gets forced to the next line due to it being too long to show in one line

Comment: Is this synchronization that you're trying to achieve between multiple text widgets, or a text widget with other sources of data? Tkinter has a way to create multiple text widgets that are perfectly synchronized.

Comment: @BryanOakley the text gets fed into a method that updates an object to represent the text, the text widget text is then set to the contents of that object because certain updates don't work properly. You can see the specific case by going to the `refresh` method on the `pyro.py` file on my GitHub repo

Comment: Also a quick sidenote. You can use `text = x.get("1.0", "end-1c")` to get all characters in the widget besides the last one. The "-1c" part reads as _[end] minus 1 character_ (you can use other numbers too). Basically it does the same thing as you do with slicing which is unneccessary and also there is not much need in using those constants as they just represent the same name lowercase string,which means that you can alternatively use `text = x.get("1.0", tkinter.END + "-1c")`. Could you also provide some function that shows how you get the data? Perhaps a simple loop counting onwards.

Comment: @Matiiss I'm not sure what you mean by some function that gets the data?